# How to remove %0D%0A from end of a parameter in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to hit a URL after generating the data to be filled for the parameters that are passed in URL using Python in back end. So the flow is:

1. User lands on a page with a form having some drop downs.
2. Python code in the backend reads the content from a file and returns single output based on some conditions for each of the dropdown.
3. User hits the submit button with the data.

The data gets generated correctly but when I hit submit button, I get %0D%0A characters at the end of the parameter values in the URL

E.g., sample.php?param1=20%0D%0A&param2=50%0D%0A

How do I get rid of these values as this is causing trouble with the other code where I am using these values?

Answer (score 1):

I take it you read the data from a file, so probably reading the file causes the line endings to be read as well.

<strike>In any case, try using `strip()` or `rstrip()` in your Python code to remove all/trailing whitespace before your assemble the target URL.</strike>

I understand that it's actually a PHP script that assembles the URL. In that case, use PHP's `trim()` function on the variables you use to assemble the URL.

For example: Assume that `$val1` and `$val2` are read from a file or some other place. Then the following line assembles above URL stripping whitespace from `$val1` and `$val2`.

```
$url = "sample.php?param1=" . trim($val1) . "&param2=" . trim($val2);
```

Comment: Hi. tried using strip but the same didn't work. It seems that the change is happening at php end

Comment: I understood it wrong, maybe - so you are preparing the URL in PHP? In that case, use the `trim()` function in PHP to strip whitespace before assembling the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers do that automatically, you can try decoding it back using urldecode()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: I guess that the newline is unwanted in both URL and the parameter values, so he should try to just not add them to the parameter in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?Php
$str = "Your Inputed Value or string" 
$url =  str_replace(" ","-", $str);
?>

<a href="<?php echo $url ?>">Link Menu</a>
```